# how to execute a .exe program by php script

Tags: php

I want to execute a .exe file on my Apache server using a php script.
the procedure is as follow:

1. user comes, fills a html form
2. it goses to a php script
3. php script executes the `name.exe` file
4. php prints the output of the `name.exe` file on the page.

I execute the name.exe normally from windows like this:

`run--> cmd--> D:\name [command]`

the name.exe needs to communicate with other files like libraries in the same directory.

the complete comand in cmd at windows is like this:

`D:\name library.dll [input from user]`

then program executes and prints some results in cmd window.

I actually want to run this program on my server form my clients.
I don't know how, but I now there is a way to do this.

Another related question, is there any shell that I can install on Linux server and execute name.exe in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please rethink your solution as this will likely create more problems (particularly security issues) than  it solves. By having a PHP script execute your program you run the danger of a user entering the following into your form:

```
John Doe; rm \windows\*
```

or

```
John Doe; rm d:\name\*
```

You want to limit user input to a very controlled subset so that you won't get malicious command injection.

PHP does provide an `exec()` but be very careful.

Comment: thanks i will. That is a good poit. I can check the input with my format before allowing it to execute by php script. But is the problem is solvable with `exec()` ? so I can study using it.

Comment: Executing external programs isn't that much of a problem with some care and escaping all incoming data with `escapeshellarg()`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [passthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) or [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

As for Linux, if `name.exe` runs well under [WINE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)), you would probably want to use `passthru()` or [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) and call WINE to run `name.exe`. I have no idea what name.exe does, so even if it *runs* under WINE, there's no guarantee that it will actually *work*.

There is, however no magic shell that allows Linux to execute arbitrary Windows executables.

As noted, be ***very*** careful of what you allow to get to `exec()` or `passthru()` or anything else that executes code outside of your script. I'm not going to go as far as to say you probably should not be doing whatever it is that you are doing, but I'm not the one working on whatever you are working on :)

Comment: There's also no requirement that PHP *not* be run under Windows/IIS.

Comment: Actually, `exec` will return the last line after command execution. Whereas [`passthru`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) works as OP wants.

Comment: I think the `passthru` command is better, cause I have couple of lines as a result of the `name.exe`

Comment: @David Lively - I wasn't saying don't run php under windows. The OP asked if he could also get the code to work under Linux. I edited for clarity, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the user input with [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) before sending it to the command.

```
$saferinput = escapeshellarg($input);
system('D:\name library.dll '.$saferinput);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea. Aside from having to grant ridiculous permissions to the user account under which your web server is executing, which effectively gives anyone visiting your site the power to run executables, your run the risk of thread safety issues, file system locking problems, and others.

If you absolutely must use this exe, create a queuing system. Have your site put the form request into a convenient repository (say, a database), and have a service poll the database periodically to run this process. This allows separation of user accounts and associated permissions for the website and the exe, eliminates any concurrent execution issues, and decreases response latency for your site.

Some (cough) languages allow you to create this service and your site code in the same language/techology, but in this case you'll have to break out the .NET or other compiled language in order to create such a service.

Comment: thanks, but my first question is is that possible, my idea would work?
then I will think of security matters, there is a login system and just my friends can use the system, I am sure about the security, but my queston is: is that idea is possible with PHP?

Comment: John, there's no way to ensure that only your friends will be using the system. That's *why* we're required to consider security in any application. Also, note that there are functionality issues in play, not just security.

Comment: We don't know anything about the 'name' command. Maybe it is safe? Maybe he runs his web server as a user who only have access to that command. Maybe the 'name' program can have multiple running processes at once without concurrency issues. Your points are still valid of course, but they aren't unsolvable.

Comment: @Emil, anything is solveable. Or, in drag racing terms: you can't turn a pig into a ballerina, but you can make a damn fast pig.  Still, this is poor design, and I for one don't want to wind up maintaining this crap a few years down the road.

Comment: guys, this will be a private system for 5-6 of my friends. I am trying to make a unit system on web so that we can use it online. so I am sure about the users and security. the `name.exe` is a scientific mathematical program though.

Comment: David, I just think you are drawing conclusions without knowing too much about the system. Not everything done in PHP will be used by a large userbase, or even connected to the web. At my workplace we have a lot of specialised applications written in PHP which do maintainance an setup tasks, were we used PHP because everyone knows it (we're not a coding firm), and because it gets the job done.

Comment: @Emil, the driving force behind making app security a high design priority is that you can never tell who is going to wind up sitting at the wrong pc at the wrong time, and his much of a bad mood they'll be in. Good design is never a waste of time, and it's worth mentioning these issues here to maintain the integrity of the SO archive.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do this by connecting to the server using PHP SSH. There is a library (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to connect to the server via SSH. Earlier I tried connecting to the server using telnet and execte .exe. But my school admin has blocked telnet due to security reasons, so I need to work on ssh.